# Firefox Addon builder: how to keep a panel shown

Tags: firefox, panel, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

I have done a firefox addon using the Addon Builder. This addon display a panel containing a web page.
The problem I have is that I would like to keep this panel displayed and probably had a close button to hide it. Actually the panel disappear when we click out of the panel.

This is the code I use to make my panel:

```
var HauteurPopup = 400;
var LargeurPopup = 650;

function getPanel(contentURL){
    var popupPanel = require("panel").Panel({
          width:LargeurPopup,
          height:HauteurPopup,
          contentURL: contentURL
         }); 
    return popupPanel;   
}

var btn = require("toolbarbutton").ToolbarButton({
        id: 'propelink-button',
        label: 'Propulesez ce lien!',
        image: 'https://www.users.prplk.com/img/mini-logo-propel-bar.jpg',
        onCommand: function() {
            if (typeof(tabs.activeTab._worker) == 'undefined') {
                let worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
                    contentScript: btnContentScript
                });
                tabs.activeTab._worker = worker;
            }
            tabs.activeTab._worker.port.emit("btnContentScript");
            var panelPopup = myPanel.getPanel("http://example.com");        
            panelPopup.show();
        }
    });
```

Someone know how to keep this panel displayed and close it adding a button?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In xul based extensions there is an option in the creation of the panel to accomplish that ([panel.noautohide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/panel#a-panel.noautohide)). In firefox-addon-sdk it seems that it doesn't exist. See [595040 – Add a "isPersistent" attribute for panels](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=595040)

Although it is mentioned that you can do a workaround by editing panel.js, but i never tried to do that, but you may want to give it a try.